# the return value of "io.micrometer.tracing.handler.TracingObservationHandler$TracingContext.getScope()" is null

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

I upgraded from A Spring boot 2.7 to Spring boot 3.0.4 project. When I click around, all is working. But when I do a POST to login, I get this stacktrace and a 500 error. Does anyone have a clue what might be happening? It seems something with the Spring Observability?

```
2023-03-09 22:16:04,195 ERROR [http-nio-8888-exec-8] [] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.micrometer.tracing.CurrentTraceContext$Scope.close()" because the return value of "io.micrometer.tracing.handler.TracingObservationHandler$TracingContext.getScope()" is null
    at io.micrometer.tracing.handler.TracingObservationHandler.onScopeClosed(TracingObservationHandler.java:115)
    at io.micrometer.observation.ObservationHandler$FirstMatchingCompositeObservationHandler.lambda$onScopeClosed$5(ObservationHandler.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
    at io.micrometer.observation.ObservationHandler$FirstMatchingCompositeObservationHandler.onScopeClosed(ObservationHandler.java:163)
    at io.micrometer.observation.SimpleObservation.lambda$notifyOnScopeClosed$6(SimpleObservation.java:219)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayDeque$DescendingIterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayDeque.java:772)
    at io.micrometer.observation.SimpleObservation.notifyOnScopeClosed(SimpleObservation.java:219)
    at io.micrometer.observation.SimpleObservation.access$000(SimpleObservation.java:35)
    at io.micrometer.observation.SimpleObservation$SimpleScope.close(SimpleObservation.java:258)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.stop(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:271)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:287)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:143)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug and it got fixed here https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/issues/179